# Vaadin: How to get URL Parameter?

Tags: java, vaadin

I'm using Vaading 14 and i have a View with `@Route("B/details/:id?")`. How do I get the :id value?
So i have a view A that navigates with `UI.getCurrent().navigate("B/details",parameters);` to view B. The Url then looks like B/details/2.

Comment: https://vaadin.com/docs/v14/flow/routing/tutorial-router-url-parameters

Answer (score 4):

### Difference between URL Parameter and Query Parameters

> URL Parameter: `domain.com/path/value` 
> Query Parameter: `domain.com/path?key=value&key2=value2`

### For **URL Parameter** try something like this

Example url: `http://localhost:8080/B/details/123`

```java
@Route("B/details/:id?") // ? meaning optional
public class DetailsView extends Div implements BeforeEnterObserver {

    @Override
    public void beforeEnter(BeforeEnterEvent event) {
       final Optional<String> optionalId = event.getRouteParameters().get("id");
       optionalId.ifPresentOrElse(id -> {
         // id found     
       }, 
       () -> {
         // id not found     
       });
    }
}
```

URL Parameter documentation found [here](https://vaadin.com/docs/v14/flow/routing/tutorial-router-templates)

### For **Query Parameters** try something like this

Example url: `http://localhost:8080/B/details?id=123&other=value1`

```java
@Route("B/details")
public class DetailsView extends Div implements HasUrlParameter<String> {

   @Override
   public void setParameter(BeforeEvent event, @OptionalParameter String parameter) {
        Location location = event.getLocation();
        QueryParameters queryParameters = location.getQueryParameters();

        Map<String, List<String>> parametersMap = queryParameters
                .getParameters();

        System.out.println(parametersMap);
    }
}
```

Example Output: `{other=[value1], id=[123]}`

Query Parameters documentation found [here](https://vaadin.com/docs/v14/flow/routing/tutorial-router-query-parameters).

**Hint**: You can implement `HasUrlParameter` in both cases if you want and even both at the same time. The optional `parameter` represents the URL parameter.

### Tips

If you want to identify a resource use **URL parameter**. If you need things like paging, filtering, sorting, etc use **query parameters**. In this case it might seem like you want to identify one or zero resources. In that case use **URL parameter**. When there is no parameter I usually display a list of all depending on the context.

Comment: I tested it myself before I posted this message and it worked as expected. Did you implement `BeforeEnterObserver`? I could call both url's `http://localhost:8080/B/details/1` and `http://localhost:8080/B/details` just fine.

Comment: The goal is to call it with B/details?id=1 not with details/1

Comment: Ok then you need that in your question. I will change my answer now that you have provided new information.

Comment: @Avec  I like your answer but my question is how can you use the id if the view is a composite view and not a Div?   My view builds up components in the constructor dependent on the id but the id is not available yet.  The UserProfileEdit example in docs is just too simplistic.

Comment: @dmalechek I think you are supposed to ask new questions as a separate and new topic. I do not clearly understand your question. I recommend that you create a new and separate question and I believe someone will be able to help.

Comment: Thanks @Avec.   I actually worked out my problem.  My service get DI into constructor and add blank fields there, then when you get the BeforeEnterEvent, grab the id, call the service, and update an field in the view, and set the values on the UI objects.